# how to fetch data from database in php if i have two table in database and i want to fetch from one table user id to others table data

Tags: php, mysql

I have created two table name is 'orders' and 'registration' in one database. when I am registering that is working fine and when i am trying to logged in with current registration that is also working fine. but

problem is only that suppose 5 users registered there and they submitted different orders. after loggin while going to see history of orders all users are seeing the same history and all are able to see each others orders in his account after logged in . I am only trying to stop this. so that only logged users can see their own submission only. they should be able to see others user order

Comment: Do you get any errors, or have you tried anything until now?

Comment: no not getting any error

Comment: what you tried? post some code

Comment: add your php code, otherwise we can't help as we can't see what you're problem is

Comment: I have created two table name is 'order' and 'registration' in one database. when I am registering that is working fine and when i am trying to logged in with current registration that is also working fine. but

Comment: @HarryPorter: The keyword you're looking for in SQL is called `WHERE`.  Something like `SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Column = SomeValue`

Comment: 'order' is a reserved word for MySQL and it might cause problems if you use it.

Comment: @HarryPorter, what david said should help you, else read this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice?) and rearrange your question, because now we cant really help you

Comment: problem is only that suppose 5 users registered there and they submitted different orders. after loggin while going to see history of orders all users are seeing the same history and all are able to see each others orders in his account after logged in . I am only trying to stop this. so that only logged users can see their own submission only. they should be able to see others user order

Comment: @KostasMitsarakis If the queries are composed properly (i.e, with backticks), it won't interfere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As database schema is not available, I'm assuming the structure like this.
Change it where you need.

**registration** table

```
Id | firstName | lastName | email | ....
```

Where, `Id` is `Primary Key` and `auto-incremented`

**orders** table

```
orderId | userID | orderName | ...
```

Where, `orderId` is `Primary Key` and `auto-incremented` ;
`userID` is `Id` of **registration** table.

So, when you are logged in through registration table. Create one session for Id.

`$_Session['user_id'];` (`Id` of **registration** table will be stored here.)

**For viewing his/her orders**

```
<?
$userID=$_SESSION['user_id'];
$orderQuery="SELECT * FROM orders WHERE userID=$userID";
.
.//Execute Your query
.
?>
```

Comment: THANKS FOR detailed information I am going to test it. and i want one more info . how to give unique id of numbers or mix of numbers and text for orders table so that each order can be recognise by its unique id

Comment: @HarryPorter Set the `id` of the `orders` table to auto-increment. It might help you if you used the MySQL Workbench program, which allows you to directly connect to your MySQL server & view data, execute queries, etc visually.

Comment: very good answer for me and this question is really important for new learner. Thanks I got really good site

Comment: `$_Session` I assume you meant that to be the supergloblal session http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php? If so, it MUST be in uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

So in orders table you need to add column 
user id related with foreign key to table users and select orders only for logged/choosed user by id.

For exaple when user is logged you need to get his unique id.
And when he wants to see orders query onle results for this particular user.
For ex.

```
 set @loggeduser = session_id() from php. 
 Select * from oreders where userid=@loggeduser;
```

I can't comment, yet.

Comment: i think you are very close to my question

Comment: Kindly show any example elaborating what you saying

Comment: how to write set with select

Comment: set @sth = (select * from table where column1 = sth limit 1 );

Limit is important because you can't set list of results into variable.

Answer (score 0):

Like David said, you could just use something like:

```
Select * from order
where userid = logedinuserid
```

but you should also consider to rename the table order.
I just asume you have the UserID in the Orders Table...